# Can anybody explain what is the difference between their subset vectors in prob package in R?

Tags: r, vector, subset, element, probability

As a student for Probability Concepts and Applications, I was following my textbook guide to use R's "prob" package when I met these subset matters below.

Please look at them and let me know the difference between subset codes I made. I expected Prob(A) 0.5 which was given 0.1666667 form R. Then I tried subset C if R couldn't get vector type input. Prob(C) showed as if it can't accept vector type input. But subset D and B worked with vector style well. The other experiment was with subset E, in which I found the "prob function" seems to hate 4 and 6 after 2... :)

If anyone can explain these symptom, please help me~~

```
> S = rolldie(1, makespace=TRUE)

> A = subset(S, X1 == c(2, 4, 6))

> Prob(A)

[1] 0.1666667

> C = subset(S, X1 == c(2, 4))

> Prob(C)

[1] 0.1666667

> D = subset(S, X1 == c(1, 2))

> Prob(D)

[1] 0.3333333

> B = subset(S, X1 == c(3,6))

> Prob(B)

[1] 0.3333333

> E = subset(S, X1 == c(4, 5, 6))

> Prob(E)

[1] 0.5

> E = subset(S, X1 == c(2, 4, 6))

> Prob(E)

[1] 0.1666667
```

Comment: All of them needs `%in%` instead of `==` i.e. `subset(S, X1 %in% c(2, 4, 6))` `==` is elementwise comparison and works only when the lengths are same or one of the vectors i.e. rhs is of length 1 (recycling happens)

Comment: Wonderful! akrun, thanks much!